# Struggling with C# generic HashSet declaration

Tags: c#, generics, hashset

I'm trying to declare something like this in C# (note this is NOT correct C# syntax):

```
enum Color { Red, Yellow, Green, Blue }
type ColorSet HashSet<Color>;                        // #1

void setColors (ColorSet colors = { Red, Green })    // #2
{ ... }
```

So -- how can I declare a synonym type for HashSet, and how can I define a constant of that type to use e.g. as a function parameter default value?

For #1, a possible approach is an empty wrapper class:

```
class ColorSet : HashSet<Color> { }
```

-- but how do I define a constant of that class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to *do* here?

Comment: Marc Gravell: Just as I wrote: I want to use a single type name for the "set of colors" because it is used many times, e.g. as a function parameter. And for defining a default value for the parameter, I'd need a constant definition or a literal.

Comment: the only constant you can use there is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
public enum Color { Red, Yellow, Green, Blue }    
public class ColorSet : HashSet<Color> {}

private void setColors(ColorSet colors = null)
{
    if (colors == null)
        colors = new ColorSet {Color.Red, Color.Green};

    ....
}
```

Note that C# compiler requires method's default parameters to be comile-time defiite, so you can't use any static instance of ColorSet as default parameter for method. Instead assume null is default parameter and in that case use predefined colorset you need in method body.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I declare a synonym type for HashSet,

You can't; there is no such thing in C#. There is a `using` *alias*, but that is per-file.

> and how can I define a constant of that type to use e.g. as a function parameter default value?

You can't: a class cannot be a constant (except `string` literals). You could have a `static readonly` field somewhere, but it would be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly set the (not null) default value for reference type for the method, but you can create two methods that act similar:

```
enum Color { Red, Yellow, Green, Blue }
class ColorSet : HashSet<Color> { }

void setColors(ColorSet colors)
{
    ...
}
void setColors()
{
    setColors(new ColorSet { Color.Red, Color.Green });
}
```

Comment: Your solution and Andy's are equally useful, I think. :-)